# Package flacards - newcommand

Tags: packages, package-options, renewcommand

I'm using `flacards`, and every card is composed of, in the frontside

1. a word with
2. it's category behind it, and in the backside
3. the translation and
4. a sample phrase behind it.

For instance

```
\card{è \\ \textmd{ind.pre.}}{es/está \\ {\scriptsize È meglio essere uccel di bosco, che uccel di gabbia.}}
```

Instead of writing every time the complete code I wish to define a command (is it the right way to call it?) such that to print a new card I just write

```
\nc{(1)}{(2)}{(3)}{(4)}
```

or something of the like, as simplifies as possible.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In theory the following basic macro should work, although I did not test it: `\newcommand{\nc}[4]{\card{#1 \\ \textmd{#2}}{#3 \\ {\scriptsize #4}}}`.

Comment: @epR8GaYuh Thank you so much ! I works perfectly.